# Laravel spatie permissions check user role inside model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-7, laravel-permission

I use in my project composer package for laravel [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). How I can check the user role for contains the inside model with `hasRole()` method?

**Example**

This not working inside the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles, SoftDeletes;

    public function orders()
    {
        if($this->hasRole("client")) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried this case outside of model all work:

```
$user = User::find(4);
if($user->hasRole("client")) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Are you using the below code in your model?
  `use HasRoles;` 
  if not then add this within your model class;

Comment: This trait is already connected in my controller @MuktiRaniGhosh

Comment: You have to connect it with your model class. You are accessing the hasRole() method from your model that has written in HasRoles trait but you are connecting this trait in your controller.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote a controller instead of model @MuktiRaniGhosh

Comment: I edited my question especially for you, adding the full code of my model @MuktiRaniGhosh

Comment: Not working means? Have you got any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209922/discussion-between-mukti-rani-ghosh-and-andreas-hunter).